# StatusBar Background Color in Expo (React Native) doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, expo

StatusBar **backgroundColor** prop doesn't work, in Expo Snack too. Work only props **hidden** and **barStyle**. Code example from Expo Snack:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor="white" barStyle="dark-content" hidden={false} translucent={false}/>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone! Save to get a shareable url.
        </Text>
        <Card>
          <AssetExample />
        </Card>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I also tried to add a style in the app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    ...
    "androidStatusBar": {
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
"androidStatusBarColor": "#ffffff", "androidStatusBar": { "barStyle": "dark-content", "backgroundColor": "#ffffff" }
```

What do i wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's an Expo problem, the community has been asking for a solution for some time. But it seems that in the next versions of Expo the problem will be solved.

You can follow this situation here: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2813

Comment: The problem was solved on Expo SDK37 release.